# npm script defined in package.json throws errors

Tags: javascript, node.js, eslint, package.json, frisby.js

I've installed the `eslint` package and added a series of scripts to `package.json`.

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js",
    "test": "node_modules/.bin/jasmine-node spec --color --verbose --autotest --watch .",
    "acceptance": "node_modules/.bin/forever stopall && node_modules/.bin/forever start index.js && ./node_modules/.bin/jasmine-node test/ --verbose && node_modules/.bin/forever stopall",
    "coverage": "./node_modules/.bin/istanbul cover -x **spec/** -x **index.js** -x **debug.js** jasmine-node spec",
    "doc": "node_modules/.bin/jsdoc modules/",
    "linter": "node_modules/.bin/eslint ."
}
```

When running these scripts I meet with mixed success. `npm run test`, `nom run coverage`, `nom run doc` all run without errors but `npm run acceptance` and `npm run linter` run the script then throw a series of errors, (I have copied the linter example below).

```
npm ERR! Darwin 16.0.0
npm ERR! argv "/Users/user/.nvm/versions/node/v6.7.0/bin/node"
"/Users/user/.nvm/versions/node/v6.7.0/bin/npm" "run" "linter"
npm ERR! node v6.7.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.3
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! todo@1.0.0 linter: `eslint .`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the todo@1.0.0 linter script 'eslint .'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the todo package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     eslint .
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs todo
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls todo
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Users/user/Documents/todo/npm-debug.log
```

The acceptance tests won't even start the script before running. Why am I getting these errors? The contents of `npm-debug.log` are:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/Users/user/.nvm/versions/node/v6.7.0/bin/node',
1 verbose cli   '/Users/user/.nvm/versions/node/v6.7.0/bin/npm',
1 verbose cli   'run',
1 verbose cli   'linter' ]
2 info using npm@3.10.3
3 info using node@v6.7.0
4 verbose run-script [ 'prelinter', 'linter', 'postlinter' ]
5 info lifecycle todo@1.0.0~prelinter: todo@1.0.0
6 silly lifecycle todo@1.0.0~prelinter: no script for prelinter, continuing
7 info lifecycle todo@1.0.0~linter: todo@1.0.0
8 verbose lifecycle todo@1.0.0~linter: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
9 verbose lifecycle todo@1.0.0~linter: PATH: /Users/user/.nvm/versions/node/v6.7.0/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/node-gyp-bin:/Users/user/Documents/todo/node_modules/.bin:/Users/user/.nvm/versions/node/v6.7.0/bin:/Users/user/google-cloud-sdk/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin:/Users/user/.nvm/versions/node/v6.7.0/bin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/texbin
10 verbose lifecycle todo@1.0.0~linter: CWD: /Users/user/Documents/todo
11 silly lifecycle todo@1.0.0~linter: Args: [ '-c', 'eslint .' ]
12 silly lifecycle todo@1.0.0~linter: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
13 info lifecycle todo@1.0.0~linter: Failed to exec linter script
14 verbose stack Error: todo@1.0.0 linter: `eslint .`
14 verbose stack Exit status 1
14 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/Users/user/.nvm/versions/node/v6.7.0/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/lifecycle.js:242:16)
14 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
14 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:191:7)
14 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/Users/user/.nvm/versions/node/v6.7.0/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/spawn.js:40:14)
14 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
14 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
14 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:877:16)
14 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:226:5)
15 verbose pkgid todo@1.0.0
16 verbose cwd /Users/user/Documents/todo
17 error Darwin 16.0.0
18 error argv "/Users/user/.nvm/versions/node/v6.7.0/bin/node" "/Users/user/.nvm/versions/node/v6.7.0/bin/npm" "run" "linter"
19 error node v6.7.0
20 error npm  v3.10.3
21 error code ELIFECYCLE
22 error todo@1.0.0 linter: `eslint .`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the todo@1.0.0 linter script 'eslint .'.
23 error Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
23 error If you do, this is most likely a problem with the todo package,
23 error not with npm itself.
23 error Tell the author that this fails on your system:
23 error     eslint .
23 error You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
23 error     npm bugs todo
23 error Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
23 error     npm owner ls todo
23 error There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Comment: Did you check the file */Users/user/Documents/todo/npm-debug.log*?

Comment: Another test you could launch the failing step manually to understand the error. The command is shown in the error, just try to execute it and check the result. If you don't got, come back here and post the detailed error.

Comment: I've included the log data  in the original post. The linter runs correctly whether I run it in manually or through an npm script. The difference is that when run as an npm script I then get this error :(

Comment: Can you paste your package.json file? Might be missing some dependencies

Comment: The `ELIFECYCLE` error is the error that I see if I run `eslint` without a `.eslintrc` file. Do you have a `.eslintrc` file? (Also, you should not need to specify `node_modules/.bin/` in your `script` entries; `"eslint ."` should be all you need.)