# npm error code ELIFECYCLE when pressing CTRL+C

Tags: npm

I've built a web scraping tool using mainly puppeteer for backend and inquirer.js for the CLI.
I want the end user to be able to exit the process without errors by pressing CTRL + C. This works perfectly when running `node built/index.js`, but when running `npm start`, pressing CTRL + C results in an error:

```
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! jmtool@1.0.0 start: `node built/index.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the jmtool@1.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Andi\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-07-28T09_46_38_541Z-debug.log
```

Here's the full log file:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'start' ]
2 info using npm@6.4.1
3 info using node@v10.15.0
4 verbose run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]
5 info lifecycle jmtool@1.0.0~prestart: jmtool@1.0.0
6 info lifecycle jmtool@1.0.0~start: jmtool@1.0.0
7 verbose lifecycle jmtool@1.0.0~start: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle jmtool@1.0.0~start: PATH: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin;C:\Users\Andi\OneDrive - Fachhochschule Dortmund\Bachelorarbeit\jmtool\node_modules\.bin;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\PuTTY\;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA NvDLISR;C:\Users\Andi\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\;C:\Users\Andi\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\Andi\AppData\Roaming\npm;%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;
9 verbose lifecycle jmtool@1.0.0~start: CWD: C:\Users\Andi\OneDrive - Fachhochschule Dortmund\Bachelorarbeit\jmtool
10 silly lifecycle jmtool@1.0.0~start: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'node built/index.js' ]
11 silly lifecycle jmtool@1.0.0~start: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle jmtool@1.0.0~start: Failed to exec start script
13 verbose stack Error: jmtool@1.0.0 start: `node built/index.js`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:301:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:182:13)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:182:13)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:962:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:251:5)
14 verbose pkgid jmtool@1.0.0
15 verbose cwd C:\Users\Andi\OneDrive - Fachhochschule Dortmund\Bachelorarbeit\jmtool
16 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.18363
17 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "start"
18 verbose node v10.15.0
19 verbose npm  v6.4.1
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error jmtool@1.0.0 start: `node built/index.js`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the jmtool@1.0.0 start script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

And here's my `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "jmtool",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node built/index.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "cheerio": "^1.0.0-rc.3",
    "inquirer": "^7.3.2",
    "inquirer-file-tree-selection-prompt": "^1.0.6",
    "n-readlines": "^1.0.0",
    "puppeteer": "^2.1.1",
    "puppeteer-select": "^1.0.3",
    "request": "^2.88.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^14.0.23"
  }
}
```

Any ideas on how to fix this?
(I'm using Windows 10 64bit btw, in case that is relevant..)

Comment: Try removing node_modules and package-lock.json, and then run again npm install.

Comment: @FahimaMokhtari you mean removing the dependencies in package.json, or the the actual modules themselves?

Comment: I meant removing the node_module folder and package-lock.json, not package.json

Comment: Tried it. Same error :/

Comment: :/ Try this: npm cache clean --force  and re-run npm install.

Comment: nope, same error unfortunately ..

Comment: is says it's "probably not a problem with npm", maybe I need to look somewhere else?

Comment: Take a look at the logs that appear in in the last line npm ERR.

Comment: done that too, but couldn't quite understand it. I've added it to the question now

Comment: Where is index.js located? And here's what I suggest, go to the directory where the index.js is located, and run node index.js. let me know whether the error disappears or not.

Comment: index.js is located in jmtool/built. 
As I said, the error doesn't occur when I run node index.js. It only occurs when running npm start

Comment: also the program functionality doesn't differ at all, no matter if I run node or npm (apart from that error when pressing CTRL + C)

Comment: I suspect it's a path issue on : "start": "node built/index.js" . Is test command working ? Also, make sure "node built/index.js" is correctly refered to from the package.json

Comment: Well it works fine when i run "node built/index.js" and it is correctly referred in package.json, but still the error only occurs when using "npm start"

Comment: Does test succeed? If not, the problem is at "scripts" in package.json , take a look at this:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40190315/npm-script-defined-in-package-json-throws-errors

Comment: i currently dont have a test specified as you can see

Answer (score 0):

I know the answer might be late, but I've just run into this issue. I think the problem is with the node version you're using. In my case, I was using `node v12`, changed the version to `node v14.7.0` , and then I deleted node_modules `rm -r node_modules`, I run `npm install`, and then run `npm start`, and it worked for me.

Comment: thank you but unfortunately, this doesn't work for me eithter :/ I'm not losing hope though!

Comment: Sorry to hear that :/